# Magento: change link from cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have Magento 1.7 installed, I have this theme called `ves_gift`, at the end of the Checkout (before clicking "checkout" actually) I have the terms of agreement:

[image]

The checkbox contains a link connected to the "privacy terms".

The point is that is a wrong/broken link, and I need to change its href, how do I fix it?

Also the word "Aaccetto" should be with one A only, not double. "Accetto" is the right word. Where is the translation file for that?

Comment: hi on which checkout on cart or final review checkout? and can you share your site link with me?

Comment: Sure, this is the site: https://www.ecobiobella.it/ - The point is at the end of the order.

Comment: ok please give me some time i will provide you solution....

Comment: can you please also share with me your admin username or password?

Comment: Sorry... I can't... Any other way you can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the template where the HTML contents of the checkbox. Then you can modify as per your wish.

Try installing Magento-Debug from magentocommerce, and find the template being used.

If you want to translate, then use the CSV file for translation in your theme, as per your language rather than hard-coding in Phtml files. 
Remmeber : only Html strings echoed with `$this->__('MYSAMPLETEXT');` can only be translated. So, in the CSV file you could do

```
MYSAMPLETEXT,MYTRANSLATEDTEXT
```

and then magento will translate the string for you, as simple as that.

Comment: Ok @anz, tks. But where is the file containing the PHP `$this->__('...')`? So that I can get the right variable and translate it. I know what the template being used is.

Comment: First of all you, if you are looking to translate instead of modifying, then you must be looking for a string , not variable. Strings are translated.

Comment: Secondly, install Magento-debug from magentocommerce, enable template hints in the page where you want to change the link/string, it will show the template file where the elements you are searching for resides. This is a great module which is free, for debugging magento codes. I said this because, you might have modified templates, so the template being used might vary from installation to installation.

Comment: if nothing prevails, search for "Accetto" string in your magento project file, and find the files where the string resides. It might be an already translated text, and might be in the DataBase in the worst scenario. Anyway, magento-debug will help you to locate the exact template without second-guessing or hassle.

Answer (score 0):

file path:-

app\design\frontend\default\your-theme\template\checkout\onepage\agreements.phtml

if its work vote for me, and not let me know...

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Tks for the try but is not there... My `checkout` folder contains another folder `cart` and a `cart.phtml` file, none of them has a checkbox inside.

Comment: ok you go to here now....app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\agreements.phtml, if this is not also work let me know...